# Make File upload in multiple path in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

In Example, I would like to upload ABC.jpg image in CodeIgniter, when upload image i would like to store ABC.jpg image in two folder. 1- etc/abc/folder1/ and 2-etc/abc/folder2/

How to do upload image one time store in different folder?

Here about php coding:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='etc/abc/folder1/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
$config['file_name']="ABC.jpg";
$config['max_size'] = '10000';

$this->upload->initialize($config); 
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
$imgsource='';
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}else {
$this->upload->data('userfile');
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you simply use [PHP's copy() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), to copy file from the uploaded file into a new location? you already know the name (`$config['file_name']`) and initial folder (`$config['upload_path']`), so it should be an easy thing to do

Comment: i try  to copy command in php, but it not working. can give me example.

Comment: can you post the code you tried? I might be able to help if I see what you tried